# get relative element jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I want to access an element from DOM whose parent is child of parent of parent of my current element.Messed?
Look here:

```
<div class="tr2">
    <div class="td1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" name="" />
    </div>
    <div class="td2">${index.getKey()[1]}
        <input type="hidden" name="upc" value="${index.getKey()[0]}" id="upc${index.getKey()[0]}" />
    </div>//i want to access this hidden input
    <div class="td3">
        <input type="text" name="categoryInput${counter+1 }" value="${index.getValue().toString().replace('[','').replace(']','');}" class="input" id="ct-input${counter+1 }" placeholder="Select your Category" />
    </div>//from event of this textfield
    <div class="td4"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to access hidden input in `td2` from event of text input in `td3`.

NOTE: All of this is in a loop so don't suggest any absolute element path.
May be i messed up my question feel free to edit or suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to find the closest `tr2` element and then find the `.td2 input` element in it

```
$(this).closest('.tr2').find('.td2 input')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.td3 input').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('.tr2').find('input:hidden');
});
```

References

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tr2").on("click","td3.input[type='text']",function(){

$(this).closest(".tr2").find(".td2 input:hidden");//here you get hidden input
});
```

use **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** and **[:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tr2 .td2 input')
```

this selector should help you

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent().prev().children('input[type=hidden]')`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
            $('.td3 input').change(function(){
                  $(this).parent().prev().find('input:hidden')//will give you hidden element
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

you can use **closest** solution or add additional attribute on your textbox element for example (hidden-target-id is the id of your hidden input):

```
<input hidden-target-id="upc${index.getKey()[0]}" type="text" name="categoryInput${counter+1 }" value="${index.getValue().toString().replace('[','').replace(']','');}" class="input" id="ct-input${counter+1 }" placeholder="Select your Category" />
```

-

```
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function() {
    var yourHiddenInput = $("#" + $(this).attr('hidden-target-id'));
});
```